# view state in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I can disable viewstate of each control, but not entire page.

Is there a way to disable viewstate in whole page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`Page.EnableViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx) to `false`.  This can be done either in the code-behind or in the page directive:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" %>
```

You can also disable ViewState at the application level by setting the `enableViewState` attribute of the `pages` node to `false` in your web.config:

```
<pages enableViewState="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the page declaration:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState='false' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.EnableViewState = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Page.EnableViewState="false"`

But no matter what there will be some very small ViewState footprint on any .aspx page you create.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" EnableViewState="false" %>
```